# How to add manytomanyfield with django-rest-framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I just implemented the `create` method of a ModelViewSet class. In this function, I will create a new object `Event`, and add it to manytomanyfield `events` of another object `Calendar`, Here is my code:

```
def create(self, request, calendar_pk=None):
    calendar = get_object_or_404(Calendar, guid=calendar_pk)
    serializer = EventSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()

        # if remove this two lines, it works well 
        calendar.events.add(serializer)
        calendar.save()

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

it just raise below exception

```
IntegrityError
(1062, "Duplicate entry 'e1c4570899d149e8b093773feb208328-EventSerializer(data=<QueryDict' for key 'calendar_id'")
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py in defaulterrorhandler, line 36
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problem is that you are trying to `add` a `serializer` and not an `Event` instance.

```
event = serializer.save()
calendar.events.add(event)
```

Comment: it works, thank you very much. One more question, do I need `calendar.save()` after `add` operation? I'm not sure about this

Comment: No you don't need to call `save`, after `add` it should be associated already.